# Как вывести с базы данных сумму столбика раз в неделю?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

**СТРУКТУРА ТАБЛИЦЫ И ТИПЫ ДАННЫХ**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица в которой должен проводиться отчет каждую неделю в столбик 'Status' . В этой таблице хранятся данные о "Выполненной работе "- 'Status' ,"Дата"- 'user_data' . В конце рабочей недели должно в таблице выводиться сумма часов которые отработал сотрудник за неделю . . Как это реализовать ?

**ВЕСЬ КОД ДАННОЙ СТРАНИЦЫ**

```
<?php

$sql = mysqli_query($link , "SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `Status`,`Birthday`,`user_data` FROM  `products` ");//SUM(Price) as sum
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $str=mb_convert_encoding('products', "UTF-8", "cp-1251");
    echo      
        '<tr><td>'.$result['ID'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['Status'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['Name'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['Birthday'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['user_data'].'</td>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Раз в неделю, это в какой-то определенный день недели?

Comment: В конце недели как и проводятся отчеты некоторые.

Comment: [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) вы найдете как можно узнать текущую дату и вытянуть с нее текущий день недели. Сравните его скажем с воскресеньем, и потом выполняйте запрос, иначе другой запрос

Comment: Используйте [INTERVAL 7 DAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: ($link , "SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `Status`,`Birthday`,`user_data` FROM  `products` WHERE SUM('Price') + INTERVAL 7 DAY "); Не так ?

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex, а какая структура этой конкретной таблицы и что в ней хранится - мы узнаем, исходя из... чего?) Что это за таблица-то хоть?

Comment: Зачем к сумме прибавлять интервал в днях о_О

Comment: В этой таблице хранятся данные о "Выполненной работе "- 'Status' ,"Дата"- 'user_data' . В конце рабочей недели должно в таблице выводиться сумма часов которые отработал сотрудник за неделю .

Comment: И в правду, причем тут сумма и интервал, вы хоть думаете, что делаете? Видимо, нет, раз такую ерунду пишите. Читайте документацию, вы можете использовать интервал при `INSERT` или `DELETE` включительно.

Comment: Уже сделал $sql = mysqli_query($link , "SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `Status`,`Birthday`,`user_data`, SUM(`Status`) AS `Summa` FROM  `products` ");

Comment: а за неделю чтоб - не понятно куда ..

Comment: вас несколько рас спросили, какая структура таблицы ? какой тип у поля date ? курите в сторону where date > date - INTERVAL 7 day GROUP by Name

Comment: уже изображение залил